# how to use SpringData findAll() between select when using an object as major condition?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

So there's a method in SpringData `findAll(Pageable pageable,Condition condition) ;`,
usually I use it like `findAll(pageable,myobject)` .

The question is when it comes to select some records between some certain field range ,like select out objects whose createDate are between A and B , how to use `findAll()`?

I tried `findAllByCreateDateAfterAndCreateDateBefore(Pageable pageable,Date a,Date b)`;

But here I can't put myObj as a condtion into the method , and it caused a lot trouble when some fields in the myObj are not sure if it would be used as a condition.

Comment: Can you post your entity class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JPA Specification to do this, then :

```
fun findAll(spec: Specification<YourObject>, pageable: Pageable): Page<YourObject>
```

Here simple example how it should be use :

[JPA Specification example](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any method in springdata that would be more convenient ?

Comment: The specification is very convenient and has huge power. You can define almost everything. Please if my response fit to your question vote up or accept.